# Is there a way to check for unnecessary @SuppressWarnings annotations?

Tags: android, lint

I've recently begun using annotions to help reduce my lint warning count to filter out valid use-cases of warnings/errors.

As an example, let's assume I am 100% correct in having a variable that is never assigned a value (it's being done via GSON serialization but never `x = 2` type assignment).  Lint reports this as unused variable. I can add the `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` annotation and lint skips this.

Sometime in the future, would I be able to do an assignment to the `x` variable, and then have lint notify me that the `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` flag is no longer necessary?  If not, I'd potentially have unneeded code in my application which I would like to avoid.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately no - still an open item.